# Cython extern functions from foo.h into module-like object?

Tags: namespaces, extern, cython

I'd like to do the following:

```
cdef extern from "foo.h" namespace "foo":
    int bar(int, int)

def bar(a, b):
    return foo.bar(a, b)
```

But this does not work. What is the `namespace "foo"` part for ? And how can I achieve to load the functions externed from "foo.h" into an object named foo ?

**Update**:

I could find a solution using the following file-structure and code:

```
spam.pyx
spam_c.pxd
c\
  spam.c
```

```
# spam.pyx
cimport spam_c as spam

def foo(a, b):
    return spam.foo(a, b)
```

```
# spam_c.pxd
cdef extern from "spam.c":
    double foo(double, double)
```

Is there a better way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that this is the preferred way to deal with this.